# Bind individual buttons in an ObservableCollection to a view

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm-light

I have a observable collection of buttons in a **KeyboardModel** like so

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SODemo
{
    public class KeyboardModel
    {
        public KeyboardModel()
        {
            Buttons = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
            Buttons.Add(new Button() { Name = "X", Content = "X", IsEnabled = true });
            Buttons.Add(new Button() { Name = "Y", Content = "Y", IsEnabled = false});
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Button> Buttons { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Only 2 keys are should here but in reality it will be a full keyboard and each key will be in a fixed position on screen just like a real keyboard.

I am trying to achieve a two way binding between each button in the model and the corresponding key on screen but cannot figure out how to do this.

In essence whatever button is enabled in the model should be enabled in specified position on screen (CanExecute = true).  As shown in the view I cannot use the Name parameter (Compiler error) to map the key in the view to the corresponding button in the model.

Heres the keyboard View

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SODemo"
    Height="300"
    MinWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:KeyboardModel x:Key="KeyboardModel" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ItemsControl>
        <!--          
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="Button">
                    <Button Content="{Binding Path=Does not work}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>-->

        <Canvas x:Name="DrawnKeyboard" DataContext="{StaticResource KeyboardModel}" IsEnabled="False">

            <!-- this displays first item in collection "X" as expected.. but not what I need-->
            <Button Canvas.Left="14" Canvas.Top="54" Width="64" Height="50" Content="{Binding Buttons[0]}" Name ="X"> 

            <!--Compiler error "MarkupExtensions are not allowed for Uid or Name property values, so '{Binding Path=Name}' is not valid." -->
            <Button Canvas.Left="82" Canvas.Top="54" Width="64" Height="50" Name="{Binding Path=Name}"/>


        </Canvas>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

The real project is using MVVM light and simplified for posting.    How can this be done?

Comment: Do not put Button controls in a view model collection. They are view elements, not view model elements. Instead use the ItemTemplate approach that you've commented out, and create a (view) model class that represents the state of a button.

Comment: Why you mix UI and actual logic? You can define class for your Button, for example: public class VirtualButton, that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and has properties for IsEnabled, Canvas_Top, Canvas_Left, Width, Height, Content. So this way you wouldn't have to bind EACH button separately

Comment: The Canvas (or whatever container you want to put the Buttons in) should be declared in the ItemsControl's ItemsPanel property.

Comment: The ItemTemplate approach did not work for me,  I left in in there just to show I had tried to use it.  I am using MVVM in the project just put this small project together to show the problem. I'm new to WPF as you can tell.

Comment: "The ItemTemplate approach did not work for me". Well, then make it work. It's the way to go. What you have right now is garbage.

Comment: [Start here](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this using the MVVM pattern would be to define a model class that represents a key:

```
public class Key
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public double Left { get; set; }
    public double Top { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
}
```

...and expose an ObservableCollection<Key> from your view model:

```
public class KeyboardModel
{
    public KeyboardModel()
    {
        Keys = new ObservableCollection<Key>();
        Keys.Add(new Key() { Name = "X", IsEnabled = true, Width = 65, Height = 50, Top = 54, Left = 14 });
        Keys.Add(new Key() { Name = "Y", IsEnabled = false, Width = 65, Height = 50, Top = 54, Left = 82  });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Key> Keys { get; set; }
}
```

...and present each key as a Button in the view using an ItemsControl with an ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="700" Height="700" Background="Yellow" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="Button">
            <Button Content="{Binding Name}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" 
                            Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

As stated in the comments, controls such as Buttons belong to the view only.